# How to generate api key for Laravel Restful Api

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Passport for Authentication in my Laravel-8 Restful Api.

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
    Route::post('notices/pause', 'NoticeController@pause');
    Route::get('notices/read', 'NoticeController@read');
    Route::resource('notices', 'NoticeController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
   });
```

I consume the endpoint in Angular. So far everything is working fine. However, I realise that I might need to send the endpoints to other users as external api.

How do I create api-key along with the restful api in Laravel-8?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to have a read over the [password grant tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#password-grant-tokens) documentation for Passport.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this command:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Comment: I am using php artisan passport:install